# How to re-arrange elements of Array after Deleting

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Recently I was reading a Programming book and found this question:

I have an array :

```
  array = [2,3,6,7,8,9,33,22];
```

Now, Suppose I have deleted the element at `4th` position i.e. `8` .

Now I have to rearrange the array as:

```
  Newarray = [2,3,6,7,9,33,22];
```

How Can I do this. And I have to also minimize the complexity.

**Edit** I have no choice to make another copy of it.I have to only modify it.

Comment: Get index of your deleted element and then do memcpy

Comment: `memcpy` won't work well (it's undefined to copy overlapping memory areas), instead use [`memmove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) to copy.

Comment: Or I should rather say, I assume the two arrays are different, since they have different names

Comment: Check these links: [Delete element from array](http://www.w3schools.in/c/program/delete-element-from-array/) and [c program delete element from array](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-delete-element-from-array)

Comment: To the OP: Do you want to modify the array *in place*, or do you want to copy to a *new* array?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I want to modify the array

Comment: Ok, since it is the same array, use what @JoachimPileborg suggests.

Comment: And now the tricky question: Is it a compile-time array (like e.g. `int array[8];`) or an array you allocated with e.g. `malloc`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg its compile time array... malloc is not used

Comment: @RahulMishra `Suppose I have deleted the element at 4th position` How did you delete it ? and if you have deleted it then you don't need any rearrangement then.

Answer (score 2):

You can "remove" a value from an array by simply copy over the element by the next elements, that's easy to do with [`memmove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove):

```
int array[8] = {2,3,6,7,8,9,33,22};
memmove(&array[4], &array[5], sizeof(int) * 3);
```

The resulting array will be `{2,3,6,7,9,33,22,22}`.

And from that you can see the big problem with attempting to "remove" an element from a compile-time array: You ***can't***!

You can *overwrite* the element, but the size of the array is fixed at time of compilation and can't actually be changed at run-time.

One common solution is to keep track of the actual number of valid elements in the array manually, and make sure you update that size as you add or remove elements. Either that or set unused elements to a value that's not going to be used otherwise (for example if your array can only contain positive numbers, then you could set unused elements to `-1` and check for that).

---

If you don't want to use a library function (why not?) then loop and set e.g.

```
array[4] = array[5];
array[5] = array[6];
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Do this, just use these two functions and it will work fine

```
index=4;//You wanted to delete it from the array.
memcpy(newarray,array,sizeof(array));
memmove(&newarray[index], &newarray[index + 1], sizeof(newarray)-1);
```

now the `newarray` contains your exact replica without the character that you wished to remove

Comment: Your third argument to memmove is too large

Comment: @sameera what if I don't want to use any library function?

Comment: then you'll have to run a loop, and check for the index to not copy the same, i could write it for you if you want. @RahulMishra

Answer (score 1):

You can simply displace each element from the delIdx(deletion index) one step forward.

```
for(int i=delIdx; i<(arr_size-1);i++)
{
    arr[i]= arr[i+1];
}
```

If required you can either set the last element to a non-attainable value or decrease the size of the array.